# Dimension reduction

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

$A=({B}\otimes{I_{k}})C$ where $B$ is a $N$x$r$ matrix with rank $r$, and $C$ is a $rk$x$rk$ symmetric matrix

$M=DAE$ where $D$ is a $Nk$ x $Nk$ symmetric matrix and $E$ is a $rk$x$rk$ symmetric matrix.

$F=ln(det(I_{rk}-M'M))+Tr(M'GM)-Tr(G)$ where $G$ is a symmetric $Nk$x$Nk$ matrix.

How can I end up with 
 $$F=-\sum_{n=1}^{r}ln(\lambda_{n})+\sum_{n=1}^{r}(\lambda_{n}-1)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(\lambda_{n})$$ with $r(r-1)/2$ restrictions involving the $rk$x$rk$ matrix $M$, given what follows below?

---

$rk(rk-1)/2$ restrictions are imposed involving $M$ say $m_{n}'m_{l}=0$ for all $l\ne n  = 1,2,...,rk$ where $m_{n}$ is a column of $M$.

Using these, $F$ becomes
$$F=\sum_{n=1}^{rk}ln(1-m_{n}'m_{l})+\sum_{n=1}^{rk} m_{n}'Gm_{n}-Tr(G)$$

Taking first derivatives with respect to $m_{n}$ gives
$$G m_{n}=(\frac{1}{1-m_{n}'m_{n}}) m_{n}, n=1,2,...,rk$$ and so the eigenvalues of the $G$ matrix are $\lambda_{n}=\frac{1}{1-m_{n}'m_{n}}$ and
$$F=-\sum_{n=1}^{rk}ln(\lambda_{n})+\sum_{n=1}^{rk}(\lambda_{n}-1)-\sum_{n=1}^{Nk}(\lambda_{n})$$

Comment: This question is difficult to parse. What do you mean by "end up with"? What reasons do you have to suspect that that formula for $F$ is true? What is a "restriction"? Who imposes it? The $\lambda_n$ presumably are eigenvalues of some matrix, but which one?

Comment: Thanks Federico. The formula for F is true and I can confirm it holds when k=1. The restrictions are required for identification purposes. The eigenvalues are those of the G matrix.

Comment: When k>1 I still only require r restrictions for identification rather than rk, I am thinking whether a SVD on M would somehow get me the final sums in F in terms of r and N that I need, rather than rk and Nk.